# Jquery On and Off button click

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is what I would like to accomplish. I have a div about us button that opens an about us page. I would like to disable the div about us button so that users can't click on it unless closing the about us page using the close button. Please check my attempt below. After clicking on the close button, the div about us button can't be clicked anymore.

Please check JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jvaHb/

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#btn-social').click(function(){
        var this_item = $(this).attr("data-item");
        $('.content-item').hide();
        $('.fade-container-' + this_item).fadeIn(2000);
        $('#btn-social').off('click');
    });
    $('#btn-close-social').click(function(){
        var this_item = $(this).attr("data-item");
        $('.content-item').hide();
        $('.fade-container-' + this_item).fadeIn(2000);
        $('#btn-social').on('click');
    });

    $('#btn-close-about').click(function(){
        var this_item = $(this).attr("data-item");
        $('.content-item').hide();
        $('.fade-container-' + this_item).fadeIn(2000);
        $('#btn-about').on('click');
    });

    $('#btn-about').click(function(){
        var this_item = $(this).attr("data-item");
        $('.content-item').hide();
        $('.fade-container-' + this_item).fadeIn(2000);
        $('#btn-about').off('click');

    });
    });
```

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle for this

Comment: i made an edit to my code, take a look, and oh you updated your code as well.

Comment: Please check JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jvaHb/

Comment: Sorry there's a typo in my code sample. Fixed in my answer and also in this fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/jvaHb/1/

Comment: Thanks Anthony, however the #btn-social is still clickable before clicking on #btn-close-social .Doesnt look like a typo.

Comment: That's fixed now too. Didn't notice the order of the click handlers is different between social and about. Updated with fix and also changed order so that the code is symmetrical... http://jsfiddle.net/jvaHb/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.off('click')` detaches all click handlers on `#btn-about` and `#btn-social` when the buttons are clicked and a new one is never reattached. (You don't want to detach and reattach them over and over anyway).

There are many ways to solve this. Since you don't want to hide the button, one option is to simply have a variable to indicate if the each button should be clickable...

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    var isBtnSocialClickable = true;

    $('#btn-close-social').click(function(){
        var this_item = $(this).attr("data-item");
        $('.content-item').hide();
        $('.fade-container-' + this_item).fadeIn(2000);
        isBtnSocialClickable = true;
    });

    $('#btn-social').click(function(){
        if (isBtnSocialClickable) {
            var this_item = $(this).attr("data-item");
            $('.content-item').hide();
            $('.fade-container-' + this_item).fadeIn(2000);
            isBtnSocialClickable = false;
        }
    });

    var isBtnAboutClickable = true;

    $('#btn-close-about').click(function(){
        var this_item = $(this).attr("data-item");
        $('.content-item').hide();
        $('.fade-container-' + this_item).fadeIn(2000);
        isBtnAboutClickable = true;
    });

    $('#btn-about').click(function(){
        if (isBtnAboutClickable) {
            var this_item = $(this).attr("data-item");
            $('.content-item').hide();
            $('.fade-container-' + this_item).fadeIn(2000);
            isBtnAboutClickable = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Other ways to do this would be to enable/disable the buttons, or add and remove a class on the buttons and have the onclick event's selector include the class so it won't fire when the class is removed.

Comment: Hi Anthony, I've tried your codes. The #btn-about button is still clickable before the close button is clicked. I need #btn-about button to enable after the close button is clicked and not before. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that will work

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="btn_about">About Us</a>

<div id="content">About Us content
<div class="close"><a href="#">Close Button</a></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#content { display:none;}
```

**Code**

```
$('.btn_about').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if( !$(this).is('.active') ){
        alert('Hi');
        $('#content').fadeIn();
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});

$('.close').click(function(){
    $('#content').fadeOut();
    $('.btn_about').removeClass('active');

});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jvaHb/6/)**

Comment: I tried your codes. But after clicking on the close button, the about us button is not clickable.

Comment: pls provide your code on fiddle it would be easy to find your problem

Comment: I have update my answer with my demo content. Please check http://jsfiddle.net/jvaHb/6/

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rakesh, but I've already accepted Anthony's answer. I'll upvote this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use preventDefault() and a btn variable in an if/else statement

```
$('#btn-close1').click(function(e){
    if(btn === 'off'){
        var this_item = $(this).attr("data-item");
        $('.content-item').hide();
        $('.fade-container-' + this_item).fadeIn(2000);

        btn = 'on';
    }else{
        // Stops Default Button Action
        e.preventDefault();
    }

});

$('#btn-about').click(function(){
    if(btn === 'on'){
        var this_item = $(this).attr("data-item");
        $('.content-item').hide();
        $('.fade-container-' + this_item).fadeIn(2000);

        btn = 'off';
    }else{
        // Stops Default Button Action
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```